# How to make an associative array from values of two normal arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, associative

**CODE**

```
<?php
    $a = array('31','01','02','03','30','31','01','02');
    $b = array('7','7','7','7','8','8','8','8');
    $c = array_combine($a,$b);
    var_dump($c);
?>
```

**RESULT**
It ignores the duplicate values with the same key
array(5) { [31]=> string(1) "8" ["01"]=> string(1) "8" ["02"]=> string(1) "8" ["03"]=> string(1) "7" [30]=> string(1) "8" }

**WHAT I NEED**

I need to make an associative array with keys and duplicate values separated by comma.(Here: 31th key has two values 7 and 8)

Comment: You __cannot__ have same keys in array.

Comment: Yes array cannot have same keys. However I want the values to be separated by comma wherever there is a duplicate key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your task can be solved by a simple `foreach`:

```
$c = [];
foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    if (!isset($c[$value])) {
        // there's NO key `$value` in `$c` - add it with initial value
        $c[$value] = [];
    } 

    // add new value to this key
    $c[$value][] = $b[$key];
}
// Output
// Array ( [31] => Array ( [0] => 7 [1] => 8 ) [01] => Array ( [0] => 7 [1] => 8 ) [02] => Array ( [0] => 7 [1] => 8 ) [03] => Array ( [0] => 7 ) [30] => Array ( [0] => 8 )
```

Version for comma separated values:

```
foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    if (!isset($c[$value])) {
        // there's NO key `$value` in `$c` - add it with initial value
        $c[$value] = $b[$key];
    } else {
        $c[$value] .= ',' . $b[$key];
    }
}
// Output:
// Array ( [31] => 7,8 [01] => 7,8 [02] => 7,8 [03] => 7 [30] => 8 )
```

Comment: Not sure how important 'duplicate values separated by comma' is in their requirement, but this is  a simple tweak to the else if needed.

Comment: Actually I need multiple events on the same date on PHP codeigniter calendar between start date and end date. So I require comma

Comment: __Updated__ my answer, as first version had bugs.

Comment: I need $c to be associative so that I can generate a calendar in codeigniter for multiple events and holidays...

Comment: function get_calendar($year, $month) {
        $this->load->library('calendar', $this->prefs);
        $cal_data = $this->get_calendar_data($year, $month);
        return $this->calendar->generate($year, $month, $cal_data);
    }

Comment: I think they want $c[31] to be "7,8" rather than another array with 7 and 8 as different elements.

Answer (score -1):

You can use "array_push", for example:

```
    <?php 
$a = array('31','01','02','03','30','31','01','02'); 
$b = array('7','7','7','7','8','8','8','8'); 
$c = array_push($a, $b); 
var_dump($c);
?>
```

Comment: I need an associative array in php so that I can generate a calendar in codeigniter...

Comment: $data = array(
        31  => '7','8',
        1 => '7','8',
        2 => '7','8',
        3 => '7',
);